# C# UdpClient Works Over Network But Not Over Internet With Port Forwarding

Tags: c#, udp, connection, nat

Ok so i've been developing server/client apps for a program i'm making. It works fine over the local network. I've set port forwarding up and im using my external IP address to communicate with the server app. Everything works fine but when I send the client app to my friends to launch, there is no communication to my server for them. Any suggestions?

**Server (Marked out important lines, the rest isnt necessary for solving this)**

```
 class ServerListener
{
    private string _IPAddress;
    private int _Port;
    private static UdpState _UdpState;
    private static UdpClient _UdpServer;
    private IPEndPoint _IpEndpoint;
    private static BinaryFormatter _BinaryFormatter;

    public ServerListener(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        _IPAddress = ipAddress;
        _Port = port;
        _UdpServer = new UdpClient(_Port);
        _IpEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(_IPAddress , 8000);
        _BinaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);
        _UdpState = new UdpState();
        _UdpState.IpEndPoint = _IpEndpoint;
        _UdpState.UdpClient = _UdpServer;
        _UdpServer.Client.SendTimeout = 100;
        _UdpServer.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
    }
    public void StartListenCycle()
    {
        FetchData();
    }

    private static void FetchData()
    {
        _UdpServer.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _UdpState);                  
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        FetchData();
        ClientDataRequest dataRequest;
        UdpClient udpClient = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).UdpClient;
        IPEndPoint endpoint = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).IpEndPoint;

//// ---->    This lines important  Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref endpoint);
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memStream.Write(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            dataRequest = (ClientDataRequest)_BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ClientRequestHandler.HandleRequest), dataRequest);              
        }

        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            GameState gameState = new GameState(true);
            SerializedGameState dataPacket = new SerializedGameState();
            dataPacket.Players = new PlayerInformation[GameState.Players.Count];
            gameState.ClientPlayerObjects.CopyTo(dataPacket.Players, 0);
            Serializer.Serialize(memStream, dataPacket);
            byte[] responseAsBytes = memStream.ToArray();
            try
            {
   //// ----> This lines important   udpClient.Send(responseAsBytes, responseAsBytes.Length,   endpoint);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client (same again)**

```
 class ClientNetworkConnection
    {
        private string _IPAddress;
        private int _Port;
        UdpClient _UdpClient;
        IPEndPoint _IpEndpoint;

        public ClientNetworkConnection(string ipAddress, int port)
        {
            _IPAddress = ipAddress;
            _Port = port;
            _UdpClient = new UdpClient();
            _UdpClient.Ttl = 10;
            _UdpClient.AllowNatTraversal(true);
            _IpEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_IPAddress), _Port);
            _UdpClient.Client.SendTimeout = 100;
            _UdpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
            _UdpClient.Connect(_IpEndpoint);
        }

        public void FetchData()
        {
            while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
            {
                ClientDataRequest request = new ClientDataRequest();
                request.PlayerID = DataStore.PlayerId;
                request.PlayerName = DataStore.PlayerName;
                request.PlayerClicked = DataStore.MouseDown;
                request.ClickPosition = new Point(DataStore.MousePositionX, DataStore.MousePositionY);
                SerializedGameState response = new SerializedGameState();
                byte[] objectAsBytes;
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bf.Serialize(ms, request);
                    objectAsBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
 /////// -------> Important networky stuff     _UdpClient.Send(objectAsBytes, objectAsBytes.Length);

                try
                {
/////// -------> Important networky stuff         var data = _UdpClient.Receive(ref _IpEndpoint);
                    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        response = Serializer.Deserialize<SerializedGameState>(memStream);
                        GameState.SetClientStaticVariables(response);
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    //Handle Socket exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use Wireshark on both ends to verify packets are actually getting through (or not and determine which side blocks the packets). Also ReceiveTimeout may be too small.